# My ElevatedButton not working in StackWidget. FLUTTER

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm trying use IndexStack in my app. But I have a problem with **Stack** and **ElevatedButton**. I trying press button and it don't response anything to me. But the blue button bellow is still working well
Thank for concern about my issue.

**Codepen:** https://codepen.io/sucanabo/pen/xxqPrRw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How `Stack` widget works, is that it takes the first child from the `children` list that you provide it and makes it the `base` of the rendering.

Whatever children you provide it after the first child, will be rendered on `top` of the base child.

So, when your `Positioned` child is becoming the base, your `ListView` child (which is the second in the `children` list) is being rendered on top of your `Positioned` widget, which is hence blocking all the interaction.

If you want this to work with your architecture, move the `ListView` as the first child and your `Positioned` as the second child, like this,

```
Stack(
  clipBehavior: Clip.none,
  children: [

    // First the ListView
    ListView(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 50.0, 20.0, 20.0),
      children: [],
    ),

    // Then the Positioned
    Positioned(
      top: -35.0,
      left: 0,
      right: 0,
    ),
  ],
),
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You save me <3

Comment: Glad to have helped :)